# WCF Service namespace colision, all in same solution

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

I have WCF Class library, WCF Service Client and WCF Service Server in one visual studio solution and i have problem.

In WCF Service Client i using worker classes library, using common types class library, and my `svcutil.exe` classes generated from `.wsdl` have collision with this classes.
In WCF Class library in service interface i using this same common types from class library that using this worker classes library.

Is any way to use in my solution original classes from library that i can reference in this project? And use generated classes from `.wsdl` only when i'm in other solution? or maybe i should design this in other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `/namespace` argument to [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to specify a different namespace for generated classes.

If you want to share the same datacontract definitions between both client and server that residing in your **WCF Client Library** you can skip svcutil.exe altogether and use **[ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx)** directly. The link has an example on how to do this.

Comment: Okey, but i'm working on worker classes that is programmed to using common types library, when i working on data in common type library how i can convert type from my classes to generated classes i need this for query webservice who uses generated classes, technically this is 2 different object types.?

Comment: @Svisstack please see my edit.. i kinda guessed you were trying to do this...In theory you don't need this... it is a little tricky but can be done...

Comment: why this problem appears, did i designed something wrong? I have simple class library with some working functions shared across solution and to make server and clients many clients instances that use this same data, this is simple problem i think, but in wcf solition i cant do that simple as looks like ;-( i dont like this

Comment: @Svisstack  ... WCF was not designed to share data definition between server and client in a common library. Usually the client has no access to server code and has to have redefinition of both the service interface and data being transmitted

Comment: Thanks;-) now i pretty confident that i dont like wcf in this solution

Comment: @Svisstack please dont give up because of this... once you get it to work correctly is it better than using svcutil.exe... as when you update the service and data code you don't have to run svcutil.exe again :)